# Upgrading to Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-upgrade

Have you anyone tried this so far? Did you find any issues? We thought of upgrading our SP server to SP 2010 since it provides many flexible development environment. What would suggest as best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SharePoint 2010 Upgrade Resource Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee514557.aspx) has all the information you need.